# Effective 3d array transposition with R/C++ (Rcpp)

Tags: c++, array, r, rcpp

Task is reshape 3d array from [row, col, slice] to [slice,row,col]. I tried implement `base::aperm` analog with `Rcpp`.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector array_perm(const Rcpp::NumericVector& x) {
    if (Rf_isNull(x.attr("dim"))) {
        throw std::runtime_error("'x' does not have 'dim' attibute.");
    }
    Rcpp::Dimension d = x.attr("dim");
    if (d.size() != 3) {
        throw std::runtime_error("'x' must have 3 dimensions.");
    }
    std::size_t n = d[2];
    std::size_t n_vec = d[0] * d[1];
    std::size_t n_out = n_vec * n;
    Rcpp::NumericVector res = Rcpp::no_init(n_out);
    std::size_t ind_from = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::size_t ind_to = i;
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < n_vec; ++j) {
            res[ind_to] = x[ind_from];
            ind_to += n;
            ind_from += 1;
        }
    }
    res.attr("dim") = Rcpp::Dimension(d[2], d[0], d[1]);
    return res;
}
```

How can I improve it?

For testing code:

```
# Observations
n <- 1000
# Dimension
d <- 100
# Array
a <- replicate(n, matrix(seq_len(d * d), nrow = d, ncol = d))
# Desired result
res <- aperm(a, c(3, 1, 2))
res
```

Small benchmark current variant of the code:

```
b <- bench::mark(aperm(a, c(3, 1, 2)), array_perm(a))
b[, c("expression", "min", "median", "max", "itr/sec")]
#>   expression                min   median      max `itr/sec`
#>   <chr>                <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl>
#> 1 aperm(a, c(3, 1, 2))   84.9ms   85.1ms   85.5ms     11.7 
#> 2 array_perm(a)         124.8ms  125.2ms  127.2ms      7.96
```

### RcppArmadillo solution

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::Cube<double> array_perm2(const arma::Cube<double>& x) {
    std::size_t rows = x.n_rows;
    std::size_t cols = x.n_cols;
    std::size_t slices = x.n_slices;
    arma::Cube<double> res(slices, rows, cols);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            for(std::size_t k = 0; k < slices; ++k) {
                res(k, i, j) = x(i, j, k);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Benchmark:

```
  expression                min   median      max `itr/sec`
  <chr>                <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl>
1 aperm(a, c(3, 1, 2))   85.8ms   86.4ms   87.7ms     11.6 
2 array_perm(a)         116.1ms  127.3ms  129.6ms      8.08
3 array_perm2(a)        217.4ms  219.7ms  222.1ms      4.55
```

Comment: Which version of c++ do you use or have access?

Comment: @Calak Any possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change the signature, to directly get cols, rows and slices count, you will not have to check for their validity.

```
Rcpp::NumericVector array_perm(const Rcpp::NumericVector& input, 
                               std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols, std::size_t slices);
```

Otherwise, if you can change the error management, I think you'll get a speed boost. Exceptions handling come with a cost. Maybe return an empty vector? I don't know `R` , so I don't know possibilities.

You can also try to flattening your loops, here you have multiples options:

**With the computations into output indexing**

```
Rcpp::NumericVector array_perm(const Rcpp::NumericVector& input, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols, std::size_t slices) {
    // Think about the error management here...
    auto output = Rcpp::NumericVector(Rcpp::no_init(10));

    auto rc = rows * cols;
    auto size = rc * slices;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        output[i / rc + i % rc * slices] = input[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

**With the computations into intput looking**

```
//...
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) output[i] = input[i/slices + i % slices * rc];
//...
```

**Or in reverse order**

```
//...
    while (size--) output[size] = input[size/slices + size % slices * rc];
//...
```

**Or a mix**

```
//...
    while (size--)  output[size / rc + size % rc * slices] = input[size];
//...
```

**Or even a range-based for loop**

```
//...
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for (auto e : input) {
        output[i / rc + i % rc * slices] = e;
        ++i;
    }
//...
```

*PS: Did you tried with another contiguous storage type? (std::vector, plain old C array, ...)*

*PPS: I don't have `R` environment, so I only tested transposition algorithms with c++*

**Edit**:

Two other way:

```
//...
    for(std::size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < size; ++i, j+=rc) {
        if (size <= j) j -= size - 1;
        output[i] = input[j];
    }
//...
// or
//...
    for(std::size_t i = size, j = i-1; i--; j -= rc) {
        if (size < j)  j += size-1;
        output[i] = input[j];
    }
//...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
`res[i] = vec[i/slices + i % slices * rc];` much faster than `output[i / rc + i % rc * slices] = input[i];`.

Comment: Surely because of the constness of `input`. And the "reverse order" version? Did you tried also with differents values (overall size and rows, cols or slices count)? Differents values can lead to differents results. And, the range-based version was just for completeness,  I suspected it slowest.

Comment: Reverse order the same (a little bit faster).

Comment: R `base::aperm` C implementation: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/27da0eac8bb84677002febcf12e6d61bb7358d89/src/main/array.c#L1686

Comment: Here are, in my edit, two new tries, with less calculation (but not certain of the performance gain)

Comment: So, any feedback ?

Comment: I tested almost your suggestion and choose a sequential output variant. Soon I'll update question with benchmarks. Also I tried your suggestion with tbb::paralell_for.